# Is there a standalone Flash Player for Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flash-player

I would like to download a Flash game and play it without using Firefox under Ubuntu Lucid - any ideas how?

I can download the game fine, I'm just wondering how to play it without Firefox. Is there a standalone Flash Player I can use?

Comment: In case it helps anyone, in order to transfer my save games I explored ~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#SharedObjects to find a folder with the name of the website I'd been playing it on. I then copied the folder contents into #localWithNet. HTH

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7240/how-do-i-play-swf-files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest you try Adobe's ["Linux debugger and standalone players" package (TGZ)](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/9/flash_player_9_linux_dev.tar.gz) which can be found at [Adobe Flash Player - Downloads](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).  Excerpt:

> **2/11/2010** Updated Linux debugger versions (aka debug players or content
>   debuggers) of Flash Player 9 are now
>   available. *Additionally, the **Linux
>   standalone player** (projector) is
>   available for developers who wish to
>   publish projectors on Linux operating
>   systems*  [my emphasis]

**Edit:** The newer version of this can be found [here](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_sa_debug.i386.tar.gz) - you can download & extract this, and run it by opening the `flashplayerdebugger` file.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for confirming it worked for you.

Comment: For the newer version, the link is http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_sa_debug.i386.tar.gz

Comment: Also, there is [this version](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.i386.tar.gz) available with the debugger version of Flash.

Comment: too bad that it's still 32-bit, shame that they sill haven't made a 64-bit version

Answer (score 5):

Try Gnash: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnash/

Answer (score 2):

Try CrutziPlayer: http://www.crutzi.info/crutziplayer

It executes the flash plugin, but uses xcomposite, xfixes and cairo to scale the output from native swf resolution to fullscreen.

Comment: Agreed; even though it hasn't been updated in ages at this point, CrutziPlayer still installs and runs fine on a modern (Ubuntu) system these days. I'm glad it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try Adobe's Flash Player Projector 24, which runs natively on Linux 64-bit now. I recommend using it on a 64-bit Ubuntu 16.10 system. (32-bit Linux Systems can run the 32-bit  Windows version via Wine): https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html

Answer (score -1):

If you have Ubuntu, try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

through a shell.

Comment: -1: That's the browser plugin, not the standalone player.